# Typescript React - Inferring prop type from another generic prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have the following type which represents an item store:

```js
export type ItemStore<T> = {
  allById: {
    [id: string]: T,
  },
  activeById: {
    [id: string]: T,
  },
  all: T[],
  active: T[],
  fetching: boolean,
  cursor: string,
}
```

And I have a component that utilizes an item store, but is written such that the store type is generic and it should infer the item type from the store type. I need `labelKey` and `valueKey` to accept the keys of the item type.

```js
type Props<S, I = S extends ItemStore<infer IT> ? IT : never> = {
  store: S,
  labelKey: keyof I,
  valueKey: keyof I,
}

function StoreItemList<S>(props: Props<S>): JSX.Element {
  ...
}
```

Example usage of this might be:

```js
type UserItem = {
  id: number,
  name: string,
}

const userStore: UserStore<UserItem> = { ... }

<StoreItemList
  store={userStore}
  labelKey="id"     // This should only accept 'id' and 'name' (keys of UserItem)
  valueKey="name"   // This should only accept 'id' and 'name' (keys of UserItem)
/>
```

However, this doesn't work. In the above example, it's evaluating `store` as `unknown`. Where am I going wrong?

---

**Edit:** Turns out this was ultimately an issue with the `styled-components` package I'm using. For some reason wrapping the component `styled(StoreItemList)` messes up the types. Once I removed the `styled` wrapper, the types worked as expected...

---

**Edit 2:** Looks like this is a known issue with `styled-components` when using generic components: https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components/issues/1803

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you want `props.store` to always be an `ItemStore`? In that case, it seems a bit convoluted having `Props["store"]` be a generic type `S` and then trying to constrain it by inferring the generic type `IT` of `ItemStore<IT>` that is supposed to be extended by `S`.

Instead, you could just have a single generic type representing the item, and make `props.store` be an `ItemStore<item>`:

```
type Props2<T> = { // Single generic type, no inference needed
    store: ItemStore<T>; // Force store to be a proper ItemStore
    labelKey: keyof T;
    valueKey: keyof T;
};

// Assignment of generics from component to props is straightforward, 
// no hidden generic type
function StoreItemList2<T>(props: Props2<T>) {
    // ...
}
```

With this, passing an incorrect store value type is detected:

```
<StoreItemList2
    store={userStore} // Error: Type '{ id: number; name: string; }[]' is missing the following properties from type 'ItemStore<{ id_typo: any; } & { name: any; }>': allById, activeById, all, active, and 2 more.
//  ~~~~~
    labelKey="id_typo"     // This should only accept 'id' and 'name' (keys of UserItem)
    valueKey="name"   // This should only accept 'id' and 'name' (keys of UserItem)
/>
```

And, as initially expected, incorrect label or value keys, which should be keys of the item type:

```
const userStore2: ItemStore<UserItem> = {
    allById: {
        //[id: string]: T,
    },
    activeById: {
        //[id: string]: T,
    },
    all: [],
    active: [],
    fetching: false,
    cursor: ""
};

// Item type (here UserItem) is correctly inferred automatically from type of userStore2
<StoreItemList2
    store={userStore2}
    labelKey="id_typo" // Error: Type '"id_typo"' is not assignable to type 'keyof UserItem'.
//  ~~~~~~~~
    valueKey="name" // Okay
/>
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgIilQ3wG4AocpAD0ljhgE8wk4BJGJEAZRmiQA8AFQB8cALxwA3uThy4KADaKAQozYATAFzTZ8-QG1g2uAGcYUYADsA5gF0dQgDR65AXxf70MYADckapo6MvqGxjrmlrYOcM6ucB7xSoqOBnae8t5+SKnp8ZhIMGgAFtY2OgBGEBCKqFYZcmgArlCm0BEWZS5ulEwscAAKOGCmAtxO7BJw3HA0nFYapuycPHxEAtYFUOyicAD8O3A6Vkj+UGKSIfLm-Drj8YooFUiKANJIjDoA1h8QmOwNOC+JRNJDvT5wH6MP4A8g9ciYJpWDDACBWaZrJAcLgAGWA5jGIgAFGBhqYdEMICNCQBKXT6IgwFroqxNZQUeF9VgAVVMSCg2Lwl3i4TgrJAzyggKsKBAOTMnVs3UoaDR5jgTT5UF4-CmBiuclFAEZpbL5QByABSZtM5u6EwNcFFACZTXKdFb0F87XC7BRyGNMYK8eZ4jciOIpJr+TqiD19I9nm8PuJ8MZ8KEAPSZ2KlJamYoQNkaOBoxSMBRoNBIMDwc3Gc0KBZwc0yuWNolQpYw3n8wU0+LAxSg8GpttIDNybO5-FmQvF0tWcuV6u1lsNpsl1tmjtd0v-XsClYDzMiSjZi+X7O9ZisSkjZ3CC7066YnSC2OCUQUBNPF7g75fn+IQf3kIcRw+QDoWAjl-URZEfDRDF+GDfEYEfUQSTJCkyQwkQ6UdRlmTFNlFA5ShAxQlYQ3QsNMUjaNtUxNw4GnABRKAcCgRxbxbKQnRMcVJVIMUzQ6KIbBEtw0kbWcQHxUwygYYpWEwGpFAgAB3JTSSpfkfCQJZsFwBhePND9MQEfjjAAfT6CAdBQKxGCkuAADJpFE90mxchIRHNRzlECDQJiyfxgtC5RQpRfxQubZ04BAfgADoHj-ZNGFTWz7MneRpyEPM5yLRQSzLCt0FXOsNycrdx13D5uwPLV+0HEEwRTfBx1y-LCoLYrSqXcqqxrKqNEbGqWzquBOwa-c4EPFrTxVNV4EYz9nXfFZPwEBaVmfR1kmC4J4n0bMjBMSIyhiOJ9ESLwYoCdQTEdU7M3O8SrscQE7syZQdDSQEwvlAH8kKEoyh0TAlD5QFmladoCHwOF-UoohUPMZ06P4BitXW+N5ETf8Ouy5gIAzdjOIRoQzLTDQ7NJ-BZKWKwIHgFBTEUmwZQqWoGAgUz+nNKEe2alZzVS-RwPazLOrNcmcwAeS+FBGHIJagA)

Comment: Thanks - I actually think I started out with something like this and kept trying different ways because it wasn't working. Turns out this wasn't a typescript issue but a problem with `styled-components` which is somehow messing up the types.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you need to pass a second type argument

```
export type ItemStore<T> = {
    allById: {
        [id: string]: T;
    };
    activeById: {
        [id: string]: T;
    };
    all: T[];
    active: T[];
    fetching: boolean;
    cursor: string;
};

type Props<S, I = S extends ItemStore<infer IT> ? IT : never> = {
    store: S;
    labelKey: keyof I;
    valueKey: keyof I;
};

function StoreItemList<S, I>(props: Props<S, I>): JSX.Element {
    return <div></div>;
}

type UserItem = {
    id: number;
    name: string;
};


function Foo() {
    const userStore = [
        {
            id: 1,
            name: 'James'
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            name: 'Jack'
        }
    ];

    return (
        <StoreItemList<any, UserItem>
            store={userStore}
            labelKey="id" // This should only accept 'id' and 'name' (keys of UserItem)
            valueKey="name" // This should only accept 'id' and 'name' (keys of UserItem)
        />
    );
}
```

Comment: Hmm, looks like this works - but unfortunately I've shared a simplified version and in my actual code even with these changes it's still evaluating `store` as `unknown` :/